# Исчезает изображение в ie8

Tags: html, internet-explorer, img

Без указания размера картинки отображаются.  Но вот с размером:

```
<button>Like<img style="position:absolute;width:2%;heigh" src="fl.png"></button>
```

Картинки пропадают. Как быть?

Comment: Первое что в голову приходит - не использовать ИЕ8. А если серьезно - трудно судить только по этой строчке. Нужно видеть всю картину целиком.

Comment: А почему не вешаешь фон кнопке???

Comment: Мне фон не нужен. Мне нужен текст + картинка

Comment: абсолютом относительно общего родителя

Comment: а у кого из элементов в иерархии есть position: relative? И что за "heigh" в стилях?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Следует посмотреть на наличие display: block; и высоты у элемента img, так же проверить вложенность строчных в блоковые элементов, а так же наличие явно top, left, z-index (у элемента с абсолютной он должен быть больше чем у родителя), наличие position: relative; у родителя